# Unable to control volume using keyboard button on Dell Inspiron N5010

Tags: dell, indicator-sound, oss-sound-system

After recent update I am not able to change the volume using the keyboard button. It used to work fine earlier but not anymore. All other buttons (Play/Pause, Brightness, Wireless-Enable/Disable etc) work fine. Moreover there is speaker in the notification area. It used to be there before.

In **System->Preferences**, there is no option to control sound preferences.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't mention what version of Ubuntu you are running but if it is a version up to 10.10 go to `System -> Preferences -> Sound` and a dialog box like below should pop up.

If however it is a Natty beta version then select the applications tab in Unity and search for Sound.

[image: Sound Preferences]

Ensure you have the Internal Audio selected and try a test on your speakers.

You should also check your start up programs and ensure Pulse Audio is selected by going to `System -> Preferences -> Start Up Applications` - or the applications tab in Unity and search for start up applications and ensure Pulse Audio is selected as below;

[image: Start Up Programs]

Comment: @Harbhag - happy to help, I assume from your edited question Pulse Audio was not selected to start?

Comment: I was disabling the unnecessary services to start during boot up and I un-selected the Pulse Audio by mistake.